# Verify VM is running or stopped from how long using kusto query language

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am new for kusto query language. I need some help, how to check vm is shutdown from how long and if running how long it was running. can you please help me on that because i am just starting learning on kusto query language.

[image: error image]

[image: error1 image]

[image: error3 image]

Comment: can you please resolve my issue asap

Comment: If i want to use Azure Data Explorer to write kusto query language then how can i write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 1:**

[image]

---

**Original answer:**

When the vm is stopped, there're events named `Deallocate Virtual Machine` are sent to AzureActivity table. When the vm is started to running, there're events named `Start Virtual Machine` are sent to AzureActivity table.

So it's easy to find the vm is running or stopped by the query below(in azure monitor -> Logs):

```
AzureActivity 
| where OperationName in ("Deallocate Virtual Machine","Start Virtual Machine")
| project TimeGenerated,OperationName
| top 1 by TimeGenerated desc
```

If the query result contains `Deallocate Virtual Machine`, it means the vm is in stopped status. Otherwise, it's in running status. The screenshot is as below:

[image]

Next, since we know the vm status, for example, the vm is in stopped status, then we can write query to calculate how long since it's stopped. To do that, we can use the current time to minus the time when the vm is stopped. The query like below:

```
let stop_time = AzureActivity 
| where OperationName == "Deallocate Virtual Machine" 
| project TimeGenerated
| top 1 by TimeGenerated desc;
AzureActivity
| extend the_time = now() - toscalar(stop_time)
| project the_time
| top 1 by the_time
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

You can also modify the query above to calculate the running time if the vm is now in running status.

Comment: i am getting this error while using ur solution: 'where' operator: Failed to resolve table or column expression named 'AzureActivity'

Comment: Can you please help me on that

Comment: Can u please help how to resolve this issue

Comment: @AFFISHMOHAMMAD, where did you run this query? are you running it from azure portal -> monitor -> logs?

Comment: I didn't understand why that error i am getting. can you please resolve my issues asap

Comment: @AFFISHMOHAMMAD, please show me a screenshot(like mine in the answer).

Comment: I added screenshot in my question. please check once

Comment: @AFFISHMOHAMMAD, I added a screenshot in my answer, please follow the steps in it.

Comment: I followed ur steps and did everything but getting same issue. i am added screenshot in my question what steps i followed. please check once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225304/discussion-between-ivan-yang-and-affish-mohammad).

Comment: @AFFISHMOHAMMAD, can you just run the query `AzureActivity`? see if there is any error.